# ChartFX export chart cuts the borders

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, chartfx

I have a problem with exporting a chart. I use the ChartFX chart with

```
chart.ExportImageSize = new Size(600, 450);
```

and if the size of the image is larger than this (1127, 537), it cuts the right and the bottom border in the exported image.

For exporting, I use simple

```
chart.Export(FileFormat.Bitmap);
```

No custom controls are used in exporting the chart, and the chart looks normal in the application (borders all around, and I use simple black border).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few interesting things I realized trying to solve this.
First I have no border

```
chart.Border = new SimpleBorder(SimpleBorderType.None, cOffice2007BackColor);
```

Than, I add the new border object just to export the chart with the border.

```
chart.Border = new SimpleBorder(SimpleBorderType.Color, Color.Black);
chart.Export(FileFormat.Bitmap);
```

Than I revert the border. And, it exports the chart with the new border, but it doesn't resize the border. If it's larger than ExportImageSize, I see only left and top border, and if it's smaller, I get a part of the chart that goes outside the borders.

So, I set the the border to begin with, and only change the color for the exporting.

One more realization, explicitly setting the ExportImageSize can lead to some interesting side-effects. Even dough your plot looks really good, it sometimes cuts the legend, if it is to large